# my example not working in ipod and ipad

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, ipad, ipod-touch

on scroll down, RHS panel on floating when scroll bar reach the RHS panel header. its working in all browsers but same behavioral not working in ipad/ipod/iphone.

http://www.elankeeran.com/test/RHSpanel.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that iOS doesn't support `position: fixed;`. There are JavaScript workarounds, but they're pretty clunky in comparison.